# Yii: 1.1.12 Exception.chttpexception.404 For Action Spinnerdefault.png

Tags: yii, controller, action

For a specific action of my controller, when I call that action, Yii log shows me the following error:

```
REQUEST_URI=/webapp/index.php/module_name/controller_name/spinnerDefault.png
```

My action gets called correctly and I see the correct page but this error is coming for no obvious reason and also it is not effecting any thing at all. I am unable to find the source from where "spinnerDefault.png" replaces my action which results in this error.

Any leads or ways to debug so that I could reach to the exact point from where "spinnerDefault.png" replaces my action!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is most likely due to an invalid path to "spinnerDefault.png", so Apache cannot find it and thinks it should be routed through index.php.
Find where it is declared and check if the path is correct.

Since this is a static image which should not be routed to Yii and since it is routed over index.php I am guessing there is a missing slash for the path.

Its probally defined like this:

```
<img src="spinnerDefault.png" />
```

But it should be something like:

```
<img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/spinnerDefault.png" />
```